# Why my data-binding not work on Firefox and IE11 in Polymer

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, polymer, web-component

I hava a very strange problem , this happens on firefox(i use firefox37) and IE11,but this behaved normal on chrome,the problem is: even though the `core-ajax` request was responded,and data was fetched(i can see it from devtools),data was bound automatically on chrome,but firefox and IE did not,and then ,when you click the screen or any event triggered(e.g. press F12 button),they displayed the data,i dont know why would this happen?anyone met before?

**on chrome:**

[image]

**on firefox:**

before click the screen:
[image]
after click the screen:
[image]

**on IE11:**

before click screen:
[image]
after click screen:
[image]

on firefox and IE11,before click and after click had nothing changed,no new request,no state changed,but that is the problem,it is not data-bound automatically.

**codes:**

**home-page.html:**

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/layouts/main-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html" >
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html" >
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" >
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-icon/core-icon.html" >
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-item/core-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-media-query/core-media-query.html">
<!-- <link rel="import" href="/elements/single-element.html" > -->
<polymer-element name="home-page">
    <!-- <paper-toast id="toast" text="service is not opened"></paper-toast> -->
  <template>
    <main-layout toast={{$.toast}}>
      <style>
      .chip-container {
        clear:left;
        position: relative;
        text-align:center;
        margin:120px auto;
      }

      .chip {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin: 4px;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: start;
        background-color: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
      }

      .chip-top {
        width: 250px;
        height: 200px;
      }

      .chip-bottom {
        padding: 8px;
        line-height: 1.5;
      }

      .chip-album-title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      paper-icon-button::shadow core-icon {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
      }

      </style>

      <core-ajax auto method="GET" headers='{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}'  url="{{navurl}}" handleAs="json" response="{{articlecategories}}"></core-ajax>
      <core-animated-pages selected="{{page}}" transitions="hero-transition" on-core-animated-pages-transition-end="{{complete}}">
        <!-- small -->
        <section>
          <div id="chipcontainer" layout vertical?="{{phoneScreen}}" horizontal?="{{!phoneScreen}}" center  class="chip-container" hero-p on-tap="{{transition}}">
            <div flex three></div>
            <template repeat="{{articlecategories as articlecategory}}">
              <div flex four class="chip" hero-id="{{articlecategory.id}}-{{articlecategory.name}}" hero?="{{selectedAlbum === articlecategory }}">
                <div  class="chip-top" style="background:{{articlecategory.covercolor}};" hero-id="{{articlecategory.id}}-{{articlecategory.name}}-cate" hero?="{{selectedAlbum === articlecategory}}"></div>
                <div class="chip-bottom" layout horizontal end-justified >
                  <div class="chip-album-title" flex three>
                    <div flex style="color:{{articlecategory.covercolor}}">{{articlecategory.name}}</div>
                    <div horizontal layout end>
                      <div flex style="color:{{articlecategory.covercolor}}">  {{articlecategory.totalitems}}</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div flex>
                    <a style="color:{{articlecategory.covercolor}}" href="/article/{{articlecategory.name}}"><paper-icon-button icon="arrow-forward" title="arrow-forward"></paper-icon-button></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </template>
            <div flex three></div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!-- big -->
        <template if={{!phoneScreen}}>
          <section id="details" style="padding: 50px 10% 0;">
            <div class="card" layout horizontal style="height: 400px;border-radius: 3px;text-align: start;overflow: hidden;background: #fff;box-shadow: 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);" hero-id="{{selectedAlbum.id}}-{{selectedAlbum.name}}" hero on-tap="{{transition}}">
              <div class="card-left" style="width: 400px;text-align:center;background:{{selectedAlbum.covercolor}};" hero-id="{{selectedAlbum.id}}-{{selectedAlbum.name}}-cate" hero>
                <a href="/article/{{selectedAlbum.name}}"><paper-fab class="go-url" style="margin-left:370px;margin-top:165px;background: {{selectedAlbum.covercolor}};" icon="arrow-forward" title="{{selectedAlbum.name}}"></paper-fab></a>
              </div>
              <div class="card-right" style="padding:24px;" flex>
                <div layout horizontal end-justified>
                  <div>
                    <div class="card-icon" style="border-radius: 50%;width: 60px;height: 60px;margin-right: 16px;background:{{selectedAlbum.covercolor}};"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div flex>
                    <div class="card-album-title" style="font-size: 2em;">{{selectedAlbum.name}}</div>
                    <div class="card-album-artist">{{selectedAlbum.totalitems}}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div flex>
                  <div class="card-album-description" style="font-size:200;margin:50px;">{{selectedAlbum.description}}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </section>
        </template>
        <template if={{phoneScreen}}>
          <section id="details" style="padding: 20px ;">
            <div class="card" layout vertical style="height: 400px;border-radius: 3px;text-align: start;overflow: hidden;background: #fff;box-shadow: 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);" hero-id="{{selectedAlbum.id}}-{{selectedAlbum.name}}" hero on-tap="{{transition}}">
              <div class="card-left" style="width: 400px;text-align:center;background:{{selectedAlbum.covercolor}};" hero-id="{{selectedAlbum.id}}-{{selectedAlbum.name}}-cate" hero>
                <a href="/article/{{selectedAlbum.name}}"><paper-fab class="go-url" style="margin-left:150px;margin-top:80px;background: {{selectedAlbum.covercolor}};" icon="arrow-forward" title="{{selectedAlbum.name}}"></paper-fab></a>
              </div>
              <div class="card-right" style="padding:24px;" flex>
                <div layout horizontal end-justified>
                  <div>
                    <div class="card-icon" style="border-radius: 50%;width: 60px;height: 60px;margin-right: 16px;background:{{selectedAlbum.covercolor}};"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div flex>
                    <div class="card-album-title" style="font-size: 2em;">{{selectedAlbum.name}}</div>
                    <div class="card-album-artist">{{selectedAlbum.totalitems}}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div flex>
                  <div class="card-album-description" style="font-size:200;margin:50px;">{{selectedAlbum.description}}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </section>
        </template>
      </core-animated-pages>

      <core-media-query query="max-width: 640px" queryMatches="{{phoneScreen}}"></core-media-query>
    </main-layout>
  </template>
    <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer('home-page', {
        page: 0,
        selectedAlbum: null,
        domready:function(){
        },
        transition: function(e) {
          if (this.page === 0 && e.target.templateInstance.model.articlecategory) {
            this.selectedAlbum = e.target.templateInstance.model.articlecategory;
            this.page = 1;
          } else {
            this.page = 0;
          }
        },
        phoneScreenChanged:function(){
          if(this.phoneScreen)
            this.$.chipcontainer.style.margin = '10px auto';
            else
              this.$.chipcontainer.style.margin = '120px auto';
            }
          });
        })();
        </script>
</polymer-element>

main-layout.html:

<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<!-- <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html"> -->
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-item/core-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-animation/core-animation.html" >
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-animation/core-animation-group.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-media-query/core-media-query.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/pushstate-anchor/src/pushstate-anchor.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-router/src/app-router.html">
<!-- <link rel="import" href="/layouts/single-layout.html"> -->

<polymer-element name="main-layout" attributes="toast">
  <template>

    <style shim-shadowdom>
    paper-tabs, core-toolbar {
      background-color: #00bcd4;
      color: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    core-toolbar paper-tabs {
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    paper-tabs[noink][nobar] paper-tab.core-selected {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .pink paper-tab::shadow #ink {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    paper-tabs::shadow #selectionBar{
      background-color:#ffffff;
    }
    paper-tab::shadow #ink {
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    h3 {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    #sitename {
      font-weight:bold;
    }

    paper-button::shadow core-icon {
      width: 90px;
      height: 90px;
    }
    #navheader img.profile {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 64px;
      height: 64px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    #navheader {
      /* causes console warning for incorrect mimetype */
      background-image: url("/layouts/images/background.png");
      background-size:cover;
    }
    #navheader .bottom :last-child {
      font-size: small;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
    #drawerPanel core-header-panel {
      background: #fafafa;
      box-shadow: 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      color: #757575;
    }
    paper-tabs::shadow #selectionBar{
      background-color:#ffffff;
    }
    .footer{
      margin-bottom:100px;
    }
    .headerpanel{
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    paper-ripple{
      color:#7dd6fe
    }
    </style>

    <core-ajax auto method="GET"  headers='{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}'  url="http://www.moonmoonbird.com:8888/api/v1/navigation/" handleAs="json" response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>
    <!-- drawer navigaiton -->
    <core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel" forceNarrow>
      <!-- left drawer nav -->
      <core-header-panel class="headerpanel" drawer mode="waterfall-tall">
        <paper-ripple  fit></paper-ripple>
        <core-toolbar id="navheader" class="tall">
          <paper-ripple  fit class="circle"></paper-ripple>
          <!-- </core-image> -->
        <img class="middle profile" src="/layouts/images/avatar.jpg" ></img>
        <div class="bottom" layout vertical>
          <span>Peng Kim</span>
          <span>lomoonmoonbird@gmail.com</span>
        </div>
      </core-toolbar>
          <div vertical layout >
          <div  style="line-height:30px;margin:10px;font-size:15px;text-indent: 45px;">full stack engineer ,
            love programming , astronomy , sports , making friends , uhm , 25 yo , single!</div>
            <div vertical layout style="margin:120px 10px 0px 10px;height:100%;">

              <div horizontal justified layout >
                <div>              <paper-shadow on-mouseover="{{onHovered}}" class="fab" z="0" animated layout center-center><a href="https://www.facebook.com/lomoonmoonbird" target="_blank"><paper-fab  on-mouseover="{{onHovered}}" style="background:#7dd6fe;" src="/layouts/images/social/white_facebook.png"></paper-fab></a></paper-shadow>
                </div>
                <div>              <paper-shadow class="fab" z="0" animated layout center-center><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/131857227@N04/" target="_blank"><paper-fab  style="background:#972ff8;" src="/layouts/images/social/white_flickr.png"></paper-fab></a></paper-shadow>
                </div>
                <div>              <paper-shadow class="fab" z="0" animated layout center-center><a href="https://github.com/lomoonmoonbird" target="_blank"><paper-fab style="background:#8bc34a;" src="/layouts/images/social/white_github.png"></paper-fab></a></paper-shadow>
                </div>
                <div>              <paper-shadow class="fab" z="0" animated layout center-center><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=408353888&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile_pic" target="_blank"><paper-fab  style="background:#ff5722;" src="/layouts/images/social/white_linkedin.png"></paper-fab></paper-shadow>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div horizontal justified layout>
                <div>              <paper-shadow class="fab" z="0" animated layout center-center><a href="http://www.quora.com/Lo-Moonmoonbird" target="_blank"><paper-fab   style="background:#ffeb3b;" src="/layouts/images/social/white_quora.png"></paper-fab></a></paper-shadow>
                </div>
                <div>              <paper-shadow class="fab" z="0" animated layout center-center><paper-fab   style="background:#00bcd4;" src="/layouts/images/social/white_skype.png"></paper-fab></paper-shadow>
                </div>
                <div>              <paper-shadow class="fab" z="0" animated layout center-center><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/4532062/peng-kim" target="_blank"><paper-fab  style="background:#ff4081;" src="/layouts/images/social/white_stackoverflow.png"></paper-fab></a></paper-shadow>
                </div>
                <div>              <paper-shadow class="fab" z="0" animated layout center-center><a href="https://www.tumblr.com/blog/moonmoonbird" target="_blank"><paper-fab   style="background:#ff9800;" src="/layouts/images/social/white_tumblr.png"></paper-fab><a/></paper-shadow>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div horizontal justified layout>
                <div>              <paper-shadow class="fab" z="0" animated layout center-center><a href="https://twitter.com/lomoonmoonbird" target="_blank"><paper-fab   style="background:#03a9f4;" src="/layouts/images/social/white_twitter_bird.png"></paper-fab></a></paper-shadow>
                </div>
                <div>              <paper-shadow class="fab" z="0" animated layout center-center><a href="https://vimeo.com/user39373583" target="_blank"><paper-fab  style="background:#972ff8;" src="/layouts/images/social/white_vimeo.png"></paper-fab></a></paper-shadow>
                </div>
                <div>              <paper-shadow class="fab" z="0" animated layout center-center><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCH2lj2P2y98Ojiz3jTqj7Nw" target="_blank"><paper-fab   style="background:#dc3c84;" src="/layouts/images/social/white_youtube.png"></paper-fab></a></paper-shadow>
                </div>
                <div>              <paper-shadow class="fab" z="0" animated layout center-center><a href="http://weibo.com/2033560135/profile?topnav=1&wvr=6" target="_blank"><paper-fab   style="background:#fe774d;" src="/layouts/images/social/white_sina.png"></paper-fab></a></paper-shadow>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>
          <div flex style="text-align:center;line-height:30px;margin:10px;font-size:15px;"> &copy;2015 moonmoonbird.com</div>
          <div flex></div>
        </div>
      </core-header-panel>
      <!-- end -->
      <!-- main nav -->
      <core-header-panel main  mode="waterfall">
        <core-toolbar id="mainheader" class="medium-tall">
          <!-- <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="menu" core-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button> -->
            <paper-icon-button  id="navicon" src="/layouts/images/moonmoonbird.png" core-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div horizontal layout id="sitename"  flex>Moonmoonbird</div>
            <paper-icon-button  icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-icon-button  icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
            <!-- sitename animation -->
            <core-animation-group type="par" id="sitenameanim">
              <core-animation duration="300">
                <core-animation-keyframe>
                  <core-animation-prop name="opacity" value="1">
                  </core-animation-prop>
                </core-animation-keyframe>
                <core-animation-keyframe>
                  <core-animation-prop name="opacity" value="0.3">
                  </core-animation-prop>
                </core-animation-keyframe>
                <core-animation-keyframe>
                  <core-animation-prop name="opacity" value="1">
                  </core-animation-prop>
                </core-animation-keyframe>
              </core-animation>
              <core-animation duration="300">
                <core-animation-keyframe>
                  <core-animation-prop name="transform" value="scale(1)">
                  </core-animation-prop>
                </core-animation-keyframe>
                <core-animation-keyframe>
                  <core-animation-prop name="transform" value="scale(1.2)">
                  </core-animation-prop>
                </core-animation-keyframe>
                <core-animation-keyframe>
                  <core-animation-prop name="transform" value="scale(1)">
                  </core-animation-prop>
                </core-animation-keyframe>
              </core-animation>
            </core-animation-group>
          <div class="bottom fit" horizontal layout >
            <paper-tabs id="tabs" selected="{{defaulttab}}" flex  >
              <template repeat="{{navigations as nav}}">
                <paper-tab name="{{nav.navurl}}">{{nav.name}}</paper-tab>
              </template>
          </paper-tabs>
          </div>
        </core-toolbar>
          <!-- <single-layout flex id="singlelayout" show="{{navgations[0].name}}" navurl={{navurl}}></single-layout> -->
        <content class="content"></content>
      </core-header-panel>
      <!-- end -->
      <core-media-query query="max-width: 640px"
      queryMatches="{{phoneScreen}}"></core-media-query>
    </core-drawer-panel>
  </template>
  <script>
  (function(){
    Polymer('main-layout',{
      domReady:function(){
        var animation = this.$.sitenameanim;
        animation.target = this.$.sitename;
        animation.play();
        var tabs = this.$.tabs;
        var list = this.$.singlelayout;
        var toast = this.toast;
        that = this;
        tabs.addEventListener('core-select', function() {
          if(tabs.selected != that.response[0].navurl){
            toast.show();
            return;
          }
          list.navurl = tabs.selected;
        });
      },
      responseChanged:function(oldresponse){
        this.navigations = this.response;
        this.defaulttab = this.response[0].navurl;
      },

    });
  })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="/icon.png">
  <title>moonmoonbird </title>
  <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-router/src/app-router.html">
  <style>
  html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body unresolved>
  <app-router>
    <app-route path="/" import="/pages/home-page.html"></app-route>
  </app-router>
</body>
</html>
```